# Error while posting data using PHP CURL library on production server

Tags: php, linux, api, curl, server

Currently, i am working on PHP CURL to post data to call API.
I have implemented PHP cURL to POST client_id, client_secret value to my API. CURL is working in my local server, but on my production server it's throwing an error.

`Error: "cURL error (7):  Couldn't connect to server".`

**PHP Version 5.6.24**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
if($_POST['grant_type'] != "authorization_code") 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$client_id:$client_secret");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "443");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "spider");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 600);      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);            
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Your production server probably does not allow connections to originate from it.  Try network debugging commands (ping, traceroute, telnet, ...) to confirm.  Then engage with your network guys to open the route, and or modify the firewall.  Or if this is hosted, verify the terms of use of the hoster you are using.  This question is way to generic to provide any precise answer.

Comment: Please post your cURL config and PHP version. Also, a production server is likely to have SELinux and FirewallD enforced.  Be sure to check your ports and permissions for access.  This is just a start.  You likely didn't have any security enforced on your local dev.

Comment: Please check url and credential properly.

Comment: @ManishJaiswal i checked, that one seems  correct.

Comment: @INA2N as your advice i updated my question.

Comment: try to ping on that url or ip

Comment: You're requesting port 443 for auth, but are you using port 443 for the login? Is login port 80, unsecure before going secure?  What if you try removing the CURLOPT_PROXYPORT? If the proxy is running on standard ports, this is not needed.  Did you check SELinux and FirewallD?  None of this will work without proper permissions/access.

Comment: @ManishJaiswal i can able to ping on that url from cmd line ?

Comment: @INA2N how can i check SELinux and FirewallD? can you explain me what it does?

Comment: These are security protocols in most Linux distros. You check SELinux on the command line by typing: `getenforce`

You check FirewallD by typing:  `sudo firewall-cmd --state`
Use `man firewall-cmd` to get more options
What flavor of Linux are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are security protocols in most Linux distros. You check SELinux on the command line by typing: `getenforce` You check FirewallD by typing: `sudo firewall-cmd --state` Use man firewall-cmd to get more options.

You can use `sudo firewall-cmd --list-all` to find the zones allowing http/https.  Just let me know what you find, and I can help you with additional commands.